# Does a spark cast a shadow?

Tags: visible-light, electricity, shadow

Does an electrical spark / arc cast a shadow?  For example, if you shine a flashlight through the sparks generated through a tazer, will it cast a shadow on the wall?  Unfortunately I don't have a tazer handy to conduct my own experiment here.  I know from google searches that fire does not cast (much of) a shadow, but have not been able to find out how light passes through sparks yet.

Edit: This is a bit different than fire (here, talking about an electrical arc or spark vs. fire, which may or may not behave the same).

Comment: @Sammy gerbil This is not a dupe of that question, here I am asking about sparks vs. fire.  I did not see sparks discussed in any of the answers to that question.

Comment: Both sparks and flames are made up of ionized gases which are otherwise invisible.

Comment: That's not an exact duplicate of the flame one. But, indeed, the spark discharge propagates through a plasma-like channel that is not much unlike that of a flame, the big difference being that in a spark there are only *atmospheric gases*. The main mechanisms for casting a shadow are 1) reflection, 2) refraction (depending on the definition of shadow), and 3) absorption: (1) is negligible and similar to air - no shadow; (2) if it counts, a bit stronger than with flames (higher temp.); (3) with no fuel related gases, I'd expect the absorption to be weaker. My bet? Even less shadow than flames.

Comment: A spark is an avalanche discharge; it contains free electrons, so it's a LOT different from a flame, which contains more-massive ions.   The free electrons may result in metal-like light blockage, for visible light below the plasma frequency.

Comment: May have to borrow a tazer from someone and use a flashlight to answer this :-)  Appreciate the responses so far!

Comment: Well, I tried the experiment, and as far as I can tell, a spark does not cast a shadow / block light.  It was pretty easy to verify with a tazer and a flashlight, shine the flashlight through the tazer to the wall.  However, one thought is if the spark is really pulsating (e.g. the spark is only there 1/100th of the time for example), it may be that it does cast a shadow, but it is too weak to identify.